# Can the GitHub desktop client for Windows work with non-GitHub ssh-access remotes?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have a repository on GitHub that I have cloned both on my Windows 7 laptop and on my OS X desktop.  I'll refer to these three repositories as `REPO`, `laptop`, and `desktop`.

Now, in the `laptop` repo I've used `git remote add` to add a remote called `desktop-remote`, like this:

```
% git remote add desktop-repo ssh://yourstruly@my_desktop_box/~/path/to/repo
```

This allows me to push to, and pull from, the `desktop` repo by using `git-bash` on my laptop; e.g.:

```
% git push destkop-repo some-branch
```

etc.  (In fact, I've configured my `~/.ssh` such that I can perform these operations without having to type my ssh password for `yourstruly@my_desktop_box`.  It all works great.)

OK, now add to this setup the GitHub desktop client (Windows) running on my laptop.

This client also works great as far as synchronizing the `laptop` repo and the `REPO` repo (on GitHub) goes, but I have not been able to have it recognize the *other* remote I have defined for `laptop`, namely `desktop-remote`.

Is there any way to configure the desktop client to work with an "`ssh`-accessed" non-GitHub remote such as `desktop-remote`?  Alternatively, if no special configuration is required to have this work, how can I troubleshoot the absence of the `desktop-remote` repo among the remotes defined for the `laptop` repo?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that - GitHub Desktop only uses a single remote.

From GitHub Desktop Documentation's [Frequently Asked Questions](https://help.github.com/desktop/faq/articles/can-i-work-with-multiple-remotes/):

> ### Can I work with multiple remotes?
>
> GitHub Desktop only supports adding Git remotes for the upstream repository. To work with other remotes, use Git on the command line. For more information, see "[Adding a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote)" in the *GitHub Help*.